# Screen resolution problem in cmd.exe in Full screen mode

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

When I use full screen of command line prompt (cmd.exe) in windows it gets very blurry and runs in inappropriate resolution. Is there a way around to fix this so the full screen cmd.exe is sharp and clean looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable "Full screen", Windows actually switches the display to a [text mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mode) of resolution [80x50 or 80x25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_compatible_text_mode). It does not support Linux-style framebuffer consoles, nor "fake" full-screen modes. The nearest you can get is to enlarge the console window to cover most of the screen. (The [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) wrapper may be useful.)